# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file in ASP.net Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I created web application that read excel file per row, and when i run it from my localhost it work perfectly.
But when i deploy it to web server [win 7 64 bit], it generate error like this :

```
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\TestReadExcel\testdata.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

This error came from this code (i used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel):

```
Line 195:        Dim workbook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
..
..
```

I already tried various way :

```
 1. add folder **desktop** C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\ and in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile  -it not working
 2. add security account for network services and iis_iusrs in DCOM config - microsoft excel application (allow all) - it not working
 3. already restart my web server after i configured step 1-2 , and still not working
 4. already test to add security account full control in folder C:\TestReadExcel\ , and still not working
```

Is there anything else that i need to do to solve this issue?
or is there any way than use interop excel ?

Need your help thank you.

Comment: Is is the IIS machine a different machine than you localhost?  If so, does the path `C:\TestReadExcel\testdata.xlsx` actually exist on the web server also?

Comment: IIS machine is same with my localhost, and that folder is exist

Comment: And the app pool is running under the context of the security account you mention in point 4?

Comment: Yes, app pool default use app pool user, and i already change to account network service, and do iisreset, but still not work.

Comment: Does the network service account has permission to folder mentioned ? Also my recommendation - do not use excel interop on server, use OpenXML SDK instead - you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: yes network service account had permission on that folder, full permission. did openxml can read excel file each row and column?

Answer (score 0):

use Server.Mappath to get the file path. and make sure IIS_User have read rights to that folder where you have placed your Excel File.